# Is there a way to check if one or some of multiple lines is broken?

Tags: measurement, testing

There is a product whose soldering process is often unreliable, and it has more than 50 I/O interfaces. 
Some of them should be shorted, and some are independent.

I used to test it by a multimeter to see if there is any soldering problem like broken or shorted incorrectly. Nowadays we want to test it automatically and I thought it was easy. So at first I just design a board with a MCU with its GPIOs connecting to the board to be measured, and I pulled up one of it and check others were high or low to know they were shorted or broken.

However that didn't work, I noticed there are different kinds of components between them, including resistance, capacitance and diode. So I think I have to build many small multimeter into my board, which means I need lots of components on that board, since there are 50 or more I/O and more permutations, that's unacceptable for me.

I want to ask is there a way to test all of it Fast and accurate? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Most companies that manufacture printed circuit boards also have equipment that can automatically perform continuity tests (and other tests) on the board's circuit paths as a quality control check.  These tests are usually performed as an automated process. For example, see:

- Flying probe testing ([EXAMPLE](https://youtu.be/lSNI2OTGOEE?t=10))
- Bed of nails testing
- In-circuit testing (ICT)
- Manufacturing Defect Analyzer (MDA)
- Functional Circuit Tester (FCT)
- Automated Test Equipment (ATE)

Board manufacturers usually allow customers to specify additional testing regimes such as continuity tests between adjacent pins on IC packages after the ICs are installed onto the board—e.g., misalignment of the IC package on the pads resulting in shorted pins, solder bridges resulting in shorted pins, etc.

TL;DR: Time is money. Don't waste your time performing complex and tedious tasks that can be performed by machines with far greater speed and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

fast and accurate would be a built-in self test. you may need to add parts to enable that.